# jQuery .show() .hide() animation problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

On a call to show() or hide() the animation always plays twice for me. It is much easier to understand [here](http://jsbin.com/umira4/12/edit).

A second related problem is that the animation for hide will play even if the object is already hidden (choose the first option from the drop-down and then choose the second option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you've got that setup script *inside* the dialog `<div>`.  Move that code down to the script at the bottom of the page and it should work better.

There's still the problem that it calls "hide" unnecessarily when the target box is already hidden, but that should be pretty easy to fix.

Comment: You are right thanks, that does solve the problem with the double animation. Any idea how to fix the second problem?

Comment: For the second one, maybe you could just keep track of whether the target `<div>` is already hidden?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if I save it correctly on JS Bin but here it goes:
http://jsbin.com/umira4/19/edit

I hope this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: This is good, thank you. It is unfortunate that you can't choose a hide animation style though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at .toggle( showOrHide ), http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

This will handle it for you automatically.

Comment: Ok, but then that breaks the code as it is, what should I use for the trigger now? The .change() I have does not work if I implement toggle.

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron said, there are some functions in jQuery that will take care of toggling the display of the inputs for you automatically.  I think the one you are looking for is *slideToggle()*.

Not exactly sure what the issue is, but when you clean up your JS into a separate file and use the slideToggle method it seems to work fine.

Here is what worked for me: http://jsbin.com/umira4/20/edit

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, you're example does not work very well. It seems to hide and show regardless of which of the drop-down options are chosen.

Comment: Oops, I don't think I was understanding exactly what you wanted to do....  Here is an updated solution: http://jsbin.com/umira4/29/edit - It doesn't use slideToggle anymore, but I just assigned a class of 'open' so that you can use as many options as you want without having to add logic for each unique value.